# Исключение “Can't find any valid endpoint” в Cassandra-sharp

Tags: c#, .net, cassandra

Пытаюсь подключиться к кластеру Cassandra с помощью .Net драйвера cassandra-sharp. Выходит исключение **"Can't find any valid endpoint"**. Когда я запускаю пример клиента, как на github'e драйвера (*https://github.com/pchalamet/cassandra-sharp*), ошибка происходит на любой операции после подключения к кластеру, - например, на строке с командой *Execute*:

```
using (ICluster cluster = ClusterManager.GetCluster("Cassandra"))
{   
    ICqlCommand cmd = cluster.CreatePocoCommand();
    Task t = cmd.Execute("Select * from system_schema.keyspaces").AsFuture();
...}
```

В режиме debug я вижу свои хосты в дереве *ICluster -> SingleConnectionPerEndpointStrategy -> _endpointStrategy -> NearestEndpointStrategy -> bannedEndpoints* (здесь выпадает список из IP-адресов моих нодов), и при этом 0 узлов в списке healthyEndpoints.

Более того, если попробовать подключиться к любому узлу с помощью утилиты *cqlplus.exe* (входящей в исполняемые файлы cassandra-sharp драйвера), то получается та же ошибка. С флагом */dbglog* эта утилита пишет примерно следующие сообщения:

> Creating connection to 192.168.1.3
>
> Readyfying connection for 192.168.1.3
>
> Starting writing frame for stream 127@192.168.1.3
>
> Done writing frame for stream 127@192.168.1.3
>
> Failed building connection System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
>
> at CassandraSharp.Transport.LongRunningConnection.ReadifyConnection() in ...\LongRunningConnection.cs:line 444
>
> ...
> Error creating transport for endpoint 192.168.1.3 : One or more errors occurrd.
>
> ... - marking 192.168.1.3 for recovery
>
> Command execution failed with error:
> Can't find any valid endpoint

Использую свежую версию cassandra-sharp драйвера (3.7.0). Версия Cassandra 3.11.0. Конфигурационный файл приложения *App.config* выглядит нормально. Код идеален (из примера), а значит что-то не так с настройками кластера. Сеть простая, с одним коммутатором, всё пингуется, все порты Cassandra открыты в брандмауэре Windows на клиенте. Могу добавить любую вспомогательную информацию из конфигурационного файла *cassandra.yaml*, например, используется *PropertyFileSnitch*. В консоли *cqlsh* всё работает отлично, *nodetool status* выдаёт Up&Normal.

В чём проблема, в конфигурации кластера или в .Net драйвере, и как её решить? Нужна помощь специалистов по Cassandra. Спасибо!

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://github.com/pchalamet/cassandra-sharp/issues/2) и [тут](https://github.com/pchalamet/cassandra-sharp/issues/1), может поможет.

Comment: start_native_transport: true по умолчанию теперь.
С rpc_address и local_address я поигрался - не помогает. До этого у меня были настроены rpc_interface и local_interface вместо них (потому что несколько сетевух на сервере), но даже переключив оба этих параметра в 192.168.1.3 (со значением localhost Cassandra отказалась подниматься: как я понял, не смогла установить связь с seed'ами), ошибка всё та же.

Comment: Но спасибо за наводку, задал вопрос прямо на github

Answer (score 1):

Оказывается, драйвер cassandra-sharp в настоящий момент не поддерживает Cassandra версии 3 и выше, нужно использовать 2. Разработчик посоветовал решения компании Datastax. Вопрос можно считать закрытым.